# TWS API Linux - Segmentation fault - __bid64_to_string

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

Running Cpp sample client out of the box.

I receive a segmentation fault.

`0x00005555555efba6 in __bid64_to_string ()`

Have sourced this function to client file to `Decimal.h`

`extern "C" void __bid64_to_string(char*, Decimal, unsigned int*);`

This may have something to do with the floating point library that the API documentation mentions: Intel® Decimal Floating-Point Math Library

https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/introduction.html

I have checked if this is installed on my ubuntu version, using WSL Ubuntu 20.04.05

```
libintelrdfpmath-dev/now 2.0u2-4 amd64 [installed,local]

root@flare9x:~# dpkg -s libintelrdfpmath-dev
Package: libintelrdfpmath-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 72286
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Source: intelrdfpmath
Version: 2.0u2-4
Description: Intel Decimal Floating-Point Math Library
 Software implementation of the IEEE 754-2008 Decimal Floating-Point
 Arithmetic specification, aimed at financial applications, especially
 in cases where legal requirements make it necessary to use decimal, and
 not binary floating-point arithmetic (as computation performed with
 binary floating-point operations may introduce small, but unacceptable
 errors).
Original-Maintainer: Christian Stalp <chris@chrishell.de>
Homepage: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-decimal-floating-point-math-library
```

Looking at the makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS=-pthread -Wall -Wno-switch -Wpedantic -Wno-unused-function -std=c++11
ROOT_DIR=../../../source/cppclient
BASE_SRC_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/client
INCLUDES=-I${BASE_SRC_DIR} -I${ROOT_DIR}
SHARED_LIB_DIRS=${BASE_SRC_DIR}
SHARD_LIBS=libTwsSocketClient.so
TARGET=TestCppClient

$(TARGET)Static:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(BASE_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp ./*.cpp $(BASE_SRC_DIR)/lib/libbid.a -o$(TARGET)Static

$(TARGET):
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) ./*.cpp $(BASE_SRC_DIR)/lib/libbid.so $(SHARED_LIB_DIRS)/$(SHARD_LIBS) -o$(TARGET)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(TARGET)Static *.o
```

The interesting part - I can compile the exact same code on Windows, VScode in win32.

I have tried to enforce 32bit with gcc. adding -m32.

When doing this compiler shows numerous complaints:

```
 1974 |  printf("Soft dollar tiers (%lu):", tiers.size());
      |                             ~~^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                               |               |
      |                               |               std::vector<SoftDollarTier>::size_type {aka unsigned int}
      |                               long unsigned int
      |                             %u
```

I commented out these functions  which include %lu as do not need them in main application.

Compile again, this time we have errors with the librarys that are packaged with the TWS API - the Intel decimal floating point math library, these libs come with the original TWS installation and locate:

```
/source/cppclient/client/lib/libbid.a
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `../../../source/cppclient/client/lib/libbid.a(bid64_string.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `../../../source/cppclient/client/lib/libbid.a(bid128_2_str_tables.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `../../../source/cppclient/client/lib/libbid.a(bid_decimal_data.o)' is incompatible with i386 output
```

win32 runs this just fine vscode.

running with ```gcc -m64``

Obtain seg fault again:

```
Thread 1 "TestCppClientSt" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555efba6 in __bid64_to_string ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00005555555efba6 in __bid64_to_string ()
#1  0x00007fffffffd940 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffffffd940 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fffffffd940 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fffffffd941 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fffffffd940 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fffffffd820 in ?? ()
#7  0x000055555555d5ff in std::iterator_traits<char*>::difference_type std::distance<char*>(char*, char*) ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Not sure what it could be at this point - WSL and running ubuntu on windows - that process manages memory? is ubuntu clashing with windows.

At this point - what else can I check / troubleshoot?

Thanks

Comment: For a start, extract a [mcve]. Also, check the bugtracker of the software you're using.

Comment: Well not sure exactly sure how to produce a repeatable example given the full API code base is quite large hence trying to step through what I have been trying to get the source of the problem. Ulrich - ok - check github no open issues - may need to go direct, Richard - yeah that was when leaving code as is and enforcing it to run 32bit. unsigned longs -- 64bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok finally got it working by locating where the intel floating point math library was located, named: `libintelrdfpmath-dev`, this was in contrast to using the library that comes with the TWS API as is, located at directory: `~/IBJts/source/cppclient/client/lib/libbid.a`
:

```
 root@Ubuntu-22:/bin# dpkg -L libintelrdfpmath-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/include
/usr/include/bid_conf.h
/usr/include/bid_functions.h
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc000.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc000b.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc001.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc001b.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc010.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc010b.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc011.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc011b.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc100.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc100b.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc101.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc101b.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc110.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc110b.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc111.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc111b.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libintelrdfpmath-dev
/usr/share/doc/libintelrdfpmath-dev/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libintelrdfpmath-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libintelrdfpmath-dev/copyright
```

I edited the `makefile` to include the path to this library, now which one?

I added

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc000.a` to my make file.

My makefile looks like:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-pthread -Wall -Wno-switch -Wpedantic -Wno-unused-function -std=c++11
ROOT_DIR=../../../source/cppclient
BASE_SRC_DIR=${ROOT_DIR}/client
INCLUDES=-I${BASE_SRC_DIR} -I${ROOT_DIR}
SHARED_LIB_DIRS=${BASE_SRC_DIR}
SHARD_LIBS=libTwsSocketClient.so
TARGET=TestCppClient

$(TARGET)Static:
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(BASE_SRC_DIR)/*.cpp ./*.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbidgcc000.a -o$(TARGET)Static

$(TARGET):
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) ./*.cpp $(BASE_SRC_DIR)/lib/libbid.so $(SHARED_LIB_DIRS)/$(SHARD_LIBS) -o$(TARGET)

clean:
rm -f $(TARGET) $(TARGET)Static *.o
```

requested real time bars, decimal places looks as intended and most of all no segmentation fault.

```
RealTimeBars. 3001 - Time: 1673241105, Open: 0.87948, High: 0.87951, Low: 0.87947, Close: 0.87951, Volume: -1, Count: -1, WAP: -1
```

hopefully this solves others issues with this.